# How to print file content to the screen in CentOS

Tags: linux, centos

I would like to learn -How to print file content to the screen in CentOS?

Comment: do you mean ```screen``` multiplexer or just terminal screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a text file: `cat` *filename*

Comment: `cat` is mostly useless for this, as the text will keep going, if it is more than a screen full.

Comment: I was tempted to say "cat more or less" but resisted that  urge to pun in response to a beginner question.  I decided not to suggest less or more as their behaviour changes depending on file size.

Comment: Yes `more` or `less` change to do the right thing. They always show a page at a time. The number of times it pauses depends on the number of lines in the files. I would not say this is a change in behaviour. `cat` always spits out the concatenation of the files mentioned in the argument list, and does not care if it will fit on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use `less`, it will show one page at a time. Press <kbd>q</kbd> to quit, <kbd>enter</kbd> to move forward one line, <kbd>space</kbd> to move one page, and <kbd>h</kbd> for help.